# What's the meaning of the phrase "Sunday afternoon name"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrase-meaning

In [a computerphile video](https://youtu.be/Ks0SOn8hjG8?t=517), professor Ross Anderson says that

> EMV is the Sunday afternoon name for chip & PIN, it's Europay / Mastercard / Visa protocol.

As I understand this phrase means something like an alias, but can you please explain the exact meaning, usage, and perhaps the etymology of the phrase?

Comment: I guess it's related to "Sunday clothes/dress/suit" and similar phrases for a formal outfit such as is worn to church, and therefore means "formal name". I can't find any direct evidence though, such as the question requires (googling "Sunday afternoon" will take some work).

Comment: I've heard it as [Sunday name](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sunday_name).

Comment: [Village opts for its **Sunday-best name**:](https://www.thetelegraphandargus.co.uk/news/8059292.village-opts-for-its-sunday-best-name/) ***Carleton** will now be known by its official title - **Carleton-in-Craven** - and maps, signs and letterheads have been changed accordingly.*

Comment: Just to clarify - unlike today when most people dress casually at the weekend, it used to be the custom to wear one's best clothes on Sunday, for church and (in the case of manual workers) as a pleasant change from working clothes.

Comment: ["... professional golf was being torn apart by Godzilla in a Ben Hogan cap, or to give him his Sunday afternoon name, Bryson DeChambeau."](https://news.paddypower.com/golf/2020/08/05/uspga-championship-tips-only-the-best-prevail-at-harding-park-lawrence-donegan/) So it means full and formal, as others are suggesting with other *Sunday* variations.

Comment: @KateBunting (and StuartF), yes, it is a reasonable guess that the phrase has something to do with the custom of wearing one's best clothes on Sundays, but that still leaves puzzling the reference to **afternoons**. At the times and places when that custom prevailed, people would usually don their 'Sunday best' in the morning, when getting ready to go to church.

Comment: @jsw29 - As I said, _Sunday name_ is the expression I'm familiar with.